# How to wrap align-regexp for specific regexp in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I often use align-regexp with the regexp " [^ ]+_" on a region. So I thought I'd define a function for it so I could bind it to a key:

```
(defun align-members ()
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp " [^ ]+_"))
```

But emacs complains align-regexp takes three parameters. Looking at the docs, I see it takes BEG and END. I'm not sure how `(interactive)` stuff works in emacs, but from reading the documentation I gather I should be doing this:

```
(defun align-members (BEG END)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp BEG END " [^ ]+_"))
```

But emacs then complains somewhere deep in align-regexp's call stack that it expected `integer-or-marker-p` and instead got nil. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You should write is as the following

```el
(defun align-members (BEG END)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp BEG END (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)" " [^ ]+_") 1 1))
```

or a bit simpler

```el
(defun align-members (BEG END)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp BEG END "\\(\\s-*\\) [^ ]+_" 1 1))
```

To understand it, take a look on a `align-regexp` source, here there is a part of it.

```el
(interactive
 (append
  (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (if current-prefix-arg
      (list (read-string "Complex align using regexp: "
                         "\\(\\s-*\\)")
            (string-to-number
             (read-string
              "Parenthesis group to modify (justify if negative): " "1"))
            (string-to-number
             (read-string "Amount of spacing (or column if negative): "
                          (number-to-string align-default-spacing)))
            (y-or-n-p "Repeat throughout line? "))
    (list (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)"
                  (read-string "Align regexp: "))
          1 align-default-spacing nil))))
```

As you can see:

- it adds a string `"\\(\\s-*\\)"` to your regex
- it sets 1 and `align-default-spacing` to the optional parameters

Comment: Why doesn't align-regexp still do that for me when I call it in elisp? I don't understand why I have to do it manually only in elisp and not when I usually call it. Edit: oh, that interactive form is open with code inside it, didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

Oleg's answer is fine.

The reason that `align-regexp` fills in details for you when called
interactively is that you should be able to do the most useful things with as
few key-strokes as possible.  If you need to assert more control then use the
<kbd>C-u</kbd> prefix.

This is a common design theme for Emacs commands.

Now when you call `align-regexp` programatically, there is no need to offer
you a short-cut, since presumably the programmer wants full control by
default.

In the future, when you convert a task into an interactive `defun`, use
<kbd>C-x esc esc</kbd> to see how the command received your input after they
went through the interactive forms.

In this case, you should see something like:

```lisp
(align-regexp 185 320 "\\(\\s-*\\)" [^ ]+_" 1 1 nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `align-regexp` says

> If a prefix arg was specified, the full regexp with parenthesized
>   whitespace should be supplied

so I parenthesized the whitespace in your regexp and that seems to make it work:

```lisp
(defun align-members (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end "\\( \\)[^ ]+_"))
```

Comment: Isn't a prefix argument when you do C-u then some number before invoking the command? I haven't been doing that, so why is escaping the whitespace necessary?

Comment: @JosephGarvin You are right, that is how I understand prefix arguments. I do not know why it is necessary in this case, I'm curious too. I just tried different modifications of your function until it worked.

Comment: In general(\*), a prefix argument is a function argument which *may* be supplied using the interactive `C-u` (or similar) mechanism, and docstrings will naturally highlight any such usage, but of course that argument can also be supplied directly in elisp. (\*) This is not *always* the case, however -- it is also possible to write an interactive declaration which changes its behaviour when a prefix arg is supplied, but does not actually use that value directly as a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, I can't find any `group` in your regexp. Lack of test pattern from you, I just give my example.

Try to align code:

```
bit [4:0] a;
bit [16:0] b;
```

To:

```
bit [  4:0] a;
bit [ 16:0] b;
```

I have a working function like this with `group`:

```
(defun try-align ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((BEG (region-beginning))
        (END (region-end)))
    (align-regexp BEG END "\\[\\(.*:\\)" -1 1 0)))
```

If you remove the `group` as below, it doesn't work:

```
(defun try-align ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((BEG (region-beginning))
        (END (region-end)))
    (align-regexp BEG END "\\[.*:" -1 1 0)))
```